# Introducing a term in a first-order theory

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic

Consider, in the first-order NGB theory of sets, the following axioms:
$$\vdash\exists x\forall y(y\notin x)$$
and
$$\vdash\forall y(y\notin\varnothing)$$

The second one defines the constant $\varnothing$.
Moreover, from the second axiom we get the first by $\exists$I inference rule.

So my question is: we can replace axiom $$\vdash\exists x\forall y(y\notin x)$$ with $$\vdash\forall y(y\notin\varnothing)$$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can only write that second sentence if you have a constant symbol for "$\emptyset$". Since the language of NBG is $\{\in\}$, this isn't technically a sentence you can write.

Now, you could make an argument that maybe we should add a constant symbol to the language - but clearly we don't need it (by the first formulation).

As a side note, we don't really need the axiom of emptyset - we can get the emptyset via separation applied to an arbitrary set via the formula "$x\not=x$" (this uses the fact that the semantics for first-order logic require the domain to be nonempty).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but we have to assume the individual constant $\emptyset$ as primitive in the language.

The way used e.g. into Mendelson's textbook [see 6th ed., 2015, page 231] is to formalize $\mathsf {NBG}$ in a f-o language with a single predicate letter $A^2_2$ (i.e. $\in$) but no function letter or individual constants.

---

There is a similar situation in f-o [Peano arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#First-order_theory_of_arithmetic) $\mathsf {PA}$: the usual presentation is with the individual constant $0$ as primitive and axiom: $\forall x \ (0 \ne S(x))$, but we can dispense withh $0$ and replace the above axiom with: $\exists z \forall x \ (z \ne S(x))$.